# Django, relational querysets

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How do I express this SQL query in a Django Queryset?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.id_table2 = Table2.id_table2;
```

Be aware that the structure of `table1` implyes a `id_table2` foreign key...

Why? Because I want to replace the `id_table2` in the `Table1` `table1.object.all()` listing with values asociated to the register involved in the relation. Like this

Whithout relationship

```
| id_table1 | id_table2 | foo_field1 | bar_field1 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1         | foo1       | foo2       |
---------------------------------------------------
```

With Relationship

```
| id_table1 | foo_field2*| foo_field1 | bar_field1 |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1         | foo2       | foo1       | foo2       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Keep in mind that `foo_field2` means not only this related field, but all related fields of that register.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform that query with the Django ORM. The best you can do is use `select_related()` to also pull the fields for the other table at the same time:

```
Table1.objects.select_related('table2')
```